# "The tenant for tenant guid does not exist" even though user is listed on users endpoint?

Tags: rest, azure, outlook

I'm trying to integrate with Outlook's APIs (more specifically I want to list a users' contacts, and be able to do some CRUD on them).

I created an Azure account, an Office 365 developer account, and an application on Azure.

I am able to get an access token using the login endpoint, like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token
```

And I am able to retrieve the list of users or get a user's details with the `/users` endpoint using the bearer token too. The result of the "get user" method returns something like this:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "displayName": "Renato Oliveira",
  "givenName": "Renato",
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "surname": "Oliveira",
  "userPrincipalName": "renato.company.com.br#EXT#@renatocompanycom.onmicrosoft.com",
  "id": "<user_id>"
}
```

Of course, this is using the `/users` endpoint passing the `user_id` on it:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>
```

I can't, however, get this users's contacts. When I send a GET request to the endpoint below

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>/contacts
```

I get the error below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '<my_active_directory_tenant_id>' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "<request_id>",
      "date": "2019-03-18T20:43:16"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Why is this happening? Why does it work with `/users` but not with `/users/{id}/contacts`, even though the application has all permissions activated, and admin consent was granted for the Default Directory?

Comment: Did you use the user id which is also an email address to test?

Comment: I used the user's uuid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't reproduce your issue on my side. My steps are as below for your reference.

1.Register an Application on Azure portal and grant it graph permission.

2.Get the access token.
[image]

3.Before calling the api, you need to confirm that the account needs to be a valid email address. Mine is demo101@**.onmicrosoft.com.
[image]

4.Call the graph api.
[image]

Comment: I don't get it. My username isn't a "onmicrosoft.com" address, but my actual email address. Do you know why?

Comment: I see. You need to add a user as member, not a guest. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory  And the username must be a valid email address.

Comment: The user (my user) is not a guest. It is assigned as a "Member" with the source being "Microsoft Account". The username does not point to a valid Outlook address though. That could be the issue?  The username is a valid GSuite address with a custom domain (my company's), and I used it to create the Microsoft Account.

Comment: As you can see in the response of https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_id>, the userPrincipalName is not a valid email address. If you add a user following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory. The userPrincipalName  should be the same as the username.

Comment: But to have the same username, I need to have a custom domain assigned to my organization, and thus to my directory, correct? The AD only allows me to create `renatocompanycom.onmicrosoft.com` users, because that's the AD domain, and I can not create an user with this domain as their email.

Comment: You can assign license to the users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-groups-assign

Comment: But there are no products to assign. This is an account I'm using for a proof of concept. How can I add an Outlook or Office license to an user? I already signed up for an Office 365 developer account.

Comment: You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/subscriptions-and-billing/buy-licenses?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Not yet. Don’t worry, I’ll mark your answer as the solution if I can get it working.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Thank you. Just let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Did you find a solution? I'm having exactly the same problem trying to list calendars for a user.

Comment: @drei01 I believe that the solution, to my situation, was that I managed to get my hands on an Azure environment with an active Outlook subscription and users. From there I managed to follow the steps and proceed with my proof of concept.

Comment: Important to clarify that the answer uses oAuth1 while the question uses oAuth2

Answer (score 4):

[Authenticate with your own identity:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) This will use your own identity (the app identity). This OAuth flow is called client credentials grant flow.

'Authenticate with your own identity' is not an allowed method for Microsoft Personal accounts.

Check this source here, if any of us are using a personal account then the client credentials flow won't work for us.
https://github.com/O365/python-o365#authentication-steps