# "The tenant for tenant guid does not exist" when using GraphAPI - Even with user type as Member

Tags: c#, azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to access email using Microsoft Graph API. When I try to access the email I got the below error.

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound
>
> Message: The tenant for tenant guid '<some id>' does not exist.

Here is the code to get the emails

```
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}));

var userId = "quicksilverconnect@outlook.com"; // Tried vijaynirmal@quicksilverconnectoutlook.onmicrosoft.com also
var messageId = "Actual message id";

var email = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Messages[messageId].Request().GetAsync();
```

Here is the code to get access token

```
private const string _clientId = "xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx";
private const string _clientSecret = "xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx";
private const string _tenantName = "ecd90453-34b6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
private readonly string _uri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_tenantName}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
private const string _grantType = "client_credentials";
private const string _scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Grant_Type", _grantType),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Scope", _scope),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Client_Id", _clientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Client_Secret", _clientSecret)
    });
    var responce = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_uri, content);

    responce.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var jsonString = await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var document = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(jsonString.ToStream());

    return document.RootElement.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();
}
```

I have searched in net for solutions. I found some solutions but none of them is working for me.

1. User Type must be a Member. My user type is already Member. Original issue - [“The tenant for tenant guid does not exist” even though user is listed on users endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229894/the-tenant-for-tenant-guid-does-not-exist-even-though-user-is-listed-on-users)

   [image: My User Type is Member]
2. Using Domain as tenentId. Its not working. Original issue - [Getting "The tenant for tenant guid '' does not exist"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/382beb1c-61f3-44c9-bddb-fc64707e1c71/getting-quotthe-tenant-for-tenant-guid-ltidgt-does-not-existquot?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

   ```
    private const string _tenantName = "quicksilverconnectoutlook.onmicrosoft.com";
   ```

Some interesting observations

- I was able to get the user but not their mails. Note: In this below code, only user id is working not their email id.

  ```
    var userId = "8685e56b-b1a8-45cf-a5d1-5c5ddadd0f3e"; 
    // EmailId (quicksilverconnect@outlook.com) is not working here
    var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().GetAsync();
  ```
- I found out that if I use the access token generated by [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) then my code is working properly. So probably the issue is in my `GetAccessTokenAsync` code or its configuration details.

Update:

I want to use Application permissions not Delegated permissions because my application will use Notification Subscriptions to get a notification when a new mail is received by any users. Also, I want to get the full email details of the new mail. In short, this application will run in the background.

```
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}));

var subscription = await graphServiceClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(new Subscription()
{
    Resource = "/users/quicksilverconnect@outlook.com/messages",
    ChangeType = "created",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(3).AddHours(-1),
    NotificationUrl = "https://asdasdasd.azurewebsites.net/Outlook/NewMailListener",
    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by you don't have O365 subscription. Although you have azure subscription and have an email for your azure account, but you do not have O365 subscription. So you can just get the users by graph but can not get email messages by graph.

For this problem, you can just go to this [page](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/catalog)(login with you azure admin account) and buy O365 subscription.(for example: `Office 65 E3`)
[image]

Maybe you can also buy Exchange online(such as `Exchange Online (Plan 2)`) on the same page to access the email message.

By the way, there is a mistake in your code. You use `client_credentials` as "**Grant_Type**" and use `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`. If you want to use `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`, you need to set "**Grant_Type**" as `password` but not `client_credentials`.

To use client credential authentication, You need to install [Microsoft.Graph.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth). Note: this is a prerelease package. Here is a code snippet

```
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                            .Create(configuration.ClientId)
                                            .WithTenantId(configuration.TenantId)
                                            .WithClientSecret(configuration.ClientSecret)
                                            .Build();
var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(_clientCredentialProviderauthProvider);
```

Comment: I will test it out with a trial Office 365 account. Just out of curiosity, how the access token generated by Graph Explorer is working fine without Office 365 account?

Comment: @VijayNirmal Because the access token from Graph Explorer is for your personal account email, so you can use it to get email messages. If you want to implement in your code, you may need to change the `tenant id` in `_uri` to `common`(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`). And you need to use "password" grant flow to get the access but not "client_credentials".

Comment: I want to use Application permissions not Delegated permissions because my application will use Notification Subscriptions to get a notification when a new mail is received by any users. Also, I want to get the full email details of the new mail. In short, this application will run in the background.

Sorry for not mentioning in my original post. I thought it was irrelevant. I have updated my post.

Comment: @VijayNirmal So you need to use [client credential provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider) but not `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: Thanks... I will test it after getting Office 365 account and Mark as answer after that.