# Microsoft Graph API returns ResourceNotFound

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to write a simple mail client using MSAL4J and the Microsoft Graph API v1.0.
So I'm experimenting with the MSAL sample app from here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample

The sample query for basic user information works, but as soon as I try to get something like the content of a mailbox, it fails:

```
{"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource could not be discovered.","innerError":{"date":"2021-07-23T18:39:07","request-id":"20d75a0c-fc4b-4e76-b156-96afa1c8132d","client-request-id":"20d75a0c-fc4b-4e76-b156-96afa1c8132d"}}}
```

The query I'm testing is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages.
I think the app has the necessary permissions, everything related to emails is enabled:

[image]

But I guess I'm missing something in my app's configuration, because on Graph Explorer the query succeeds.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

I made a fresh outlook.com mail account and did the same steps again: app registration etc. Now the graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages query returns a different error in Postman:

```
{"error":{"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid 'xxxx' does not exist.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"96e8e1dd-b56b-4ada-8ece-c3562305a439","oAuthEventcV":"09Nn/Z7VN+m2qHP+lfKkVA.1.1","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant","requestId":"481fdc11-7591-4323-898b-0ad02d2224df","date":"2021-08-15T23:15:35"}}}
```

I guess there was something going on with the @live.fr mailbox?

Anyway, again, no such problem in Graph Explorer, and using the access token from Graph Explorer in Postman solves it.

**Edit 2:**

I replaced the tenant ID with "common" as explained here: ["The tenant for tenant guid does not exist" when using GraphAPI - Even with user type as Member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646335/the-tenant-for-tenant-guid-does-not-exist-when-using-graphapi-even-with-user)

It works. Now I'm trying a sendMail query. Again, no problem in Graph Explorer (or using their access token), but got AccessDenied in Postman. I'm giving up for tonight.

**Edit 3:**

I got everything to work at last: read emails, send emails. I just recreated everything from scratch. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman for the steps, with the trick of using "common" as the tenant ID.

Seems like upgrading an existing configuration (add new app permissions etc) yields unexpected results.

Comment: If you checked with Graph Explorer or POSTMAN for the Graph API and it works then you isolated the issue out of it. Check the codebase/sample that you're using. You may want to sniff the traffic to make sure your application sends the correct Graph API call with token (correct scope/permissions) or not.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I thought the problem might be that my app isn't verified, but from my understanding I should still get a consent screen. So yeah, you're probably right, I will dive more into what's the sample code is doing.

Comment: yeah, let me know how it goes...

Comment: Well, same error with Postman.
Then I saw this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/134051/mailboxnotenabledforrestapi-microsoft-graph-api-in.html
So I tested the idea of using the Graph Explorer access token in Postman, and it worked. That's kinda bad news because I hoped the issue was specific to my config.