# Outlook integration error "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound"

Tags: php, outlook, integration

Error code : OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid 'xxxx-xx-4xx20e-xx-xxxxxxxx' does not exist.

Hello i need help with outlook integration.

Here is my code how  get Token.

```
function getToken()
{
    
    $client_id = "1e34596c11-2d76-4bc9-9248-1cf77xx3d4cec1";
    $clientSecret = "t22.xxP4_2n-Bp-47XaPxx9MK_4v3~.sAwxxGOJG";

    $data = [
      'client_id'      => $client_id,
      'scope'          => "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
      'client_secret'  => $clientSecret,
      'grant_type'     => "client_credentials",
    ];


    $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/490123e3-925a-420e-be6e-6cd424199d46/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $data = json_decode($result);
    var_dump($data);
    return $data->access_token;
}
```

Here is code how send data to outlook calendar.

```
function sendData() {

  $url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/wp@marketingsharks.ee/events";
        $data_json = '{
          "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
          "Body": {
            "ContentType": "HTML",
            "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
          },
          "Start": {
              "DateTime": "2020-11-28T18:00:00",
              "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
          },
          "End": {
              "DateTime": "2020-11-29T19:00:00",
              "TimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
          },
          "Attendees": [
            {
              "EmailAddress": {
                "Address": "silvar8@hotmail.com",
                "Name": "Janet Schorr"
              },
              "Type": "Required"
            }
          ]
        }' ;


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Bearer " . getToken(),
    "Content-length: ".strlen($data_json)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($result);

}
```

Someone know what i do wrong?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Have you check these answer ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646335/the-tenant-for-tenant-guid-does-not-exist-when-using-graphapi-even-with-user
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229894/the-tenant-for-tenant-guid-does-not-exist-even-though-user-is-listed-on-users

Comment: Yes i check this answers.

Comment: If you're not having Office 365 subscription then you might be receiving this error; just having AAD subscription is not enough.

Comment: Can also be somehow without a subscription. if i use another grant_type? If i put there https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer generated token key my code this works.

Comment: Yes, when you use Microsoft Graph explorer you might be calling the me endpoint. But you can see in the above code you're using "users" (and not me), which tells that you're using flow like client credentials.